# How to place a button correctly on the bottom/right?

Tags: wpf

I try to place a button 10px from the right and bottom corner. In the Designer the button is about 10px from the corner, but not in the program (it is only 1px from the corner which looks a bit bad). Is this a bug in WPF?

```
<Window x:Class="wpftest.test"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpftest" mc:Ignorable="d" Title="test"               
        Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="207,239,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.133,-0.75"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

[image: this is how it looks in the program]
[image: this is how it looks in the Designer]

Comment: The left image is the view in the program. The right is the view in the Visual Studio 2015 Designer

Comment: Please read the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Answer (score 8):

You will definitely want to be able to understand xaml markup if you intend on using WPF or UWP.  Drag and drop in the designer rarely gives you what you really want, in my experience.  However, the designer and the properties tell you exactly what is going on. Did you see what happens if you maximize your window at runtime?  The button will be nowhere near the bottom, right corner.  It will always be 207px from the left and 239px from the top, as defined.  See below for a quick explanation.

- Blue - the object is constrained a distance from this edge.
- Red - the value by which the object is constrained.
- Green - the object is not constrained to this edge.

[image]

If you requirement be that the button be 10px from the right edge and 10px from the bottom, you can define that by clicking the "links" for the constraints to make the intended edges the reference edges (clicking them toggles them, so "turn off" the left and top), and adjust the values.  You'll probably want to get rid of that transform that the designer put in for you as well.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You are setting your button based on Margin. Try Changing your button to below.

```
<Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="75" Margin="10"/>
```

Comment: This seams to work but it requires manual editing of the XAML code.

Comment: @DennisR: No, it does not. Besides, you should make yourself familiar with that anyway.

Comment: Dragging and dropping controls are fine. But if you want to make sure your controls are aligned during runtime, you need to make yourself familiar with Modifying XAML.

Comment: I still believe it is a bug in WPF. why should you get a different result during runtime from what you see in Design mode? Not WYSIWYG.

Comment: XAML sucks, if you make the window bigger the stuff aligned to the bottom does not stay at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

when working with the margins, always preferred nearest side.
here for your "right side" as HorizontalAlignment and "Bottom Side" as VerticalAlignment as nearest.